# Setting date and time picker like iOS (Scroll wheel type) in ionic1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have been trying to integrate date time picker in ionic1 , but I'm not getting the format which is shown in  [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJC3P.png) ("mm/dd/yyyy HH:00 P") 12/31/1899 12:00 AM.   There were different date/time options available for ionic2 and 3, but couldn't find this format for ionic1.
As of now I'm using this tag of ionic1

`<ionic-datetimepicker date="currentDate" min="minDate" max="maxDate" callback="datePickerCallback" datetime="1">
       <button class="button button-block button-positive"> {{ currentDate | 
        date:'MMMM/dd/yyyy' }} </button>
  </ionic-datetimepicker>`

Is there any way to integrate date time picker like the scroll type wheel functionality of this (12/31/1899 12:00 AM) format ?

Comment: You want to use native timepicker right? did you check https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker?

Comment: I wanted not just time picker @MaximShoustin,  but both date and time picker together integrated. This url was great but they had only Date picker.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it resolved,

```
<ion-list> // working code
  <span class="item" ion-datetime-picker ng-model="datetimeValue" >
    {{datetimeValue| date: "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"}}
   </span>
</ion-list>
```

This is how my [Date Time picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58PaI.png) looks like.

I had tried with ion-item inside ion-list but it dint work.

```
<ion-list>  // not working
   <ion-item>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```